# It is possible to assign an Int value to an Array inside a Function in C++?

Tags: c++

It's possible to do the following code with C++:

```
myFunction(myArray, positionInsideMyArray) = myValue.
cout << myFunction[positionInsideMyArray] << endl; // Display muValue
```

How can I do that with C++?

To make my question more clear, With one value the following code work correctly,
I want to do the same thing but using an Array parameter.

```
int& myFunction(int &x){
return x;
}
```

this is the main function:

```
int x;
myFunction(x) = myValue;
cout << x << endl; // This will display myValue
```

Comment: You can do all kinds of crazy things using overloaded operator functions in C++. You need to provide more context to your question. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes. You can do all this things in C++, using `operator() `overload and `operator[]` overload.

Comment: @Yacino Just search for "c++ pass an array to a function".

Comment: @Yacion in your last codeline, did you mean to output the x variable (and see myValue)? And in the first code, are you sure you want a function to remember the array (ie. the second call needs only a index)?

Comment: @RSahu: Not to mention macros... :)

Comment: @deviantfan Yes the second call needs only an index,

Comment: @ChristianHackl, and that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int &myFunction(int *arr, size_t pos) { return arr[pos]; }

int main() {
  using std::cout;
  int myArray[30];
  size_t positionInsideMyArray = 5;
  myFunction(myArray, positionInsideMyArray) = 17.;
  cout << myArray[positionInsideMyArray] << "\n"; // Display muValue
}
```

or with error checking:

```
#include <stdexcept>

template<size_t N>
inline int &myFunction(int (&arr)[N], size_t pos) 
{
    if (pos >= N)
        throw std::runtime_error("Index out of bounds");
    return arr[pos]; 
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, Thanks :D

Comment: @Yacino But you know this is not what you asked? ... Please, for your next question, be mucn more careful with your code samples. You're shown something completely different than what you wanted, obviously. And people who answered exactly what you asked wasted their time.

Answer (score 0):

```
myFunction(myArray, positionInsideMyArray) = myValue.
cout << myFunction[positionInsideMyArray] << endl;
```

With functions alone, the second line is not possible; you'll need a class.
However, that the second call remembers `myArray` from the
first makes the whole semantics a bit strange...
A rough idea (no complete class, only for int-arrays):

```
class TheFunc
{
    int *arr;
    int &operator() (int *arr, size_t pos)
    {
        this->arr = arr;
        return arr[pos];
    }
    int &operator[] (size_t pos)
    {
        return arr[pos];
    }
};
...
TheFunc myFunction;
myFunction(myArray, positionInsideMyArray) = myValue.
cout << myFunction[positionInsideMyArray] << endl;
```

A different, more robust version, where the array it set separately:

```
class TheFunc
{
    int *arr;
    TheFunc(int *arr)
    {
        this->arr = arr;
    }
    int &operator() (size_t pos)
    {
        return arr[pos];
    }
    int &operator[] (size_t pos)
    {
        return arr[pos];
    }
};
...
TheFunc myFunction(myArray);
myFunction(positionInsideMyArray) = myValue.
cout << myFunction[positionInsideMyArray] << endl;
```